# Convert 2 column dataframe into a single row with multiple columns

Tags: pandas, pivot, transform, data-manipulation, melt

I have a dataframe of values that i'd like to turn into a single row where each key is a column and each value is a the value, with the result being a single row. It seems like it should be a simple task but im struggling to get it done. I appreciate any help wit this

**Current Table**

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| var1 | value1 |
| var2 | value2 |
| var3 | value3 |
| var4 | value4 |
| var5 | value5 |
| var6 | value6 |
| var7 | value7 |

**Goal Table**

| var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 | var5 | var6 | var7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 |

Comment: `df.set_index("key").T`?

Comment: that worked. you're the man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataFrame.Transpose() function

for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']})

   A  B
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
3  4  d
4  5  e
5  6  f
```

now

```
df.Transpose()

   0  1  2  3  4  5
A  1  2  3  4  5  6
B  a  b  c  d  e  f
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas.DataFrame.transpose

and you may need this in the futer

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html